# Invoking proxied DAO methods from Spring stand alone client :- could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-initialization

I have a **third party jar in my class path** which has some services and DAO's developed on top of S**pring 2.0.6 and Hibernate3.2.6.** I need to call some of the services and daos.

Using ***ClassPathXmlApplicationContext*** I'm able to load the application context and able to access the services and daos. Both the service and dao are following ***ProxyFactoryBean*** pattern.

Problem comes when I'm accessing a DAO which has some single valued associations.When I'm accessing associated entity I'm getting lazy initialization problem.

To solve this problem:- If it is in **my own application JAR** I'll be able to change the ***fetch type*** into ***join*** or in **DAOImpl** method I could use ***Hibernate.initialize().***

Is there a way to avoid this problem from the stand alone code itself? Or any other way to solve this issue without modifying ***applicationContext.xml*** and DAOImpl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the caller method into one single transaction.

If you have Spring transactional environment, you can put the call of the DAO services/repositories in your own service/method which is marked as `@Transactional`, or if transaction support is not enabled, but you still have spring support in your application, you can just use [TransactionTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) directly, provided by spring

```
@Autowire 
private PlatformTransactionManager txManager; 

TransactionTemplate template  = new TransactionTemplate(this.txManager); 
template.execute( new TransactionCallback<Object>(){ 
  public void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status){ 
   // work done here will be wrapped by a transaction and committed. 
   // status.setRollbackOnly(true) is called or an exception is thrown 
  } 
});
```

Otherwise you have manually handle transactionality by your own , depending on the technologies your app is using.

Comment: So, the standalone client should be a Spring service and a method in that service should be annotated with @Transactional which in turn call the other DAO/Services ?

Comment: @vtorosyan so, by this u are managing the transaction  instead of Spring?

Comment: Who will be injecting the PlatformTransactionManger here. The JVM is not aware about it

Comment: @madhairsilence I changed it to ```@Autowire```, as I wrote this is only possible if you have spring aware application.

Comment: @madhairsilence If you mean by using ```TransactionTemplate```. no Spring still manages the transaction, here you just use the transaction template provided by spring explicitly - because for example you don't have transaction management enabled (e.g. ```<tx:annotation-driven/>``` or ```@EnableTransactionManagement```)

Comment: @vtorosyan It worked,  I got the PlatformTransactionManager (implemented by HibernateTransactionManager)  from the application context, and proceeded as you have mentioned.

This link was more helpful : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic